# Weird char in generating PDF from CKEditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, tcpdf

I have issue with PDF generated from CKEditor.

I have some text typed in CKEditor:

[image]

HTML source:

[image]

Next, this text is saved in DB.

My CKEditor config looks like:

[image]

Further, above text is fetched from DB in controller, and PDF file is generated using TCPDF:

```
public function createRegulationPDF(){
        require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');

        // create new PDF document
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        // set document information
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

        $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);

        // set default monospaced font
        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

        // set image scale factor
        $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

        // set font
        $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 10);

        // add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();

        // GET CONTENT FROM DB      
        $html = $this->view->settings['reg_statement'];

        // output the HTML content
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        ....
```

And the final point, generated PDF:

[image]

The question is: what is this weird (the box) selected char?

[image]

And how to avoid it?